# list of values not in Array column Postgress

Tags: postgresql

1. I have a array column in postgress table
2. I have list of values

Want to skip all the rows which have any of the value from my list

```
Id   Subjects
1    [English, SST]
2    [Science, Maths]
3    [Hindi, Sanskrit]
```

Want to select rows where subject does not conatin any of [English, hindi, sanskrit] hence outpur should be only id = 2

Comment: What data type is the column `subjects` defined with?  You talk about arrays, but those are represented using curly braces `{...}` in Postgres. The square brackets would indicate a `jsonb` (or `json`) column.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Why use `= 'f'` instead of `NOT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having

```
create table tt
("Id" int,"Subjects" text[]); 

insert into tt values
(1,    array['English', 'SST']),
(2,    array['Science', 'Maths']),
(3,    array['Hindi', 'Sanskrit']);
```

Then

```
select "Id" from tt 
where not "Subjects" && array['English', 'Hindi', 'Sanskrit'];
```

With the array operator overlaps (elements in common).
[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmqUMz1KojE4nyQgBGs9CE/1)

Answer (score 1):

The comparison should be either

```
NOT subjects && list
```

if NULL arrays (subjects or list) should be treated as unknown,
or

```
subjects && list IS NOT TRUE
```

if NULL arrays should be treated as an empty array.

The first option returns NULL if either, or both, subjects and list are NULL.